# $.fn.DataTable.render.text is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatables, xss

I'm using jQuery Datatables version 1.10.7 and I want to use the rendering function to prevent XSS attacks:

```
    "processing" : true,
    "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "order" : [ [ 0, "asc" ] ],
    "columnDefs": [    
                   {                                 
                       "targets": '_all',
                       "render": $.fn.DataTable.render.text()
                   }    
                 ], 
    "aoColumns" : [
    {
        "mData" : "name",
        "defaultContent" : " "
    },
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.render.text is not a function

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly note that it should be `$.fn.dataTables`, not `$.fn.DataTables`. Note the lowercase `d`.

Secondly, thanks to @davidkonrad, `render.text()` is only available from version 1.10.10, so for this to work you will also need to update your version of DataTables.

```
"processing": true,
"bJQueryUI": true,
"order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
"columnDefs": [{     
  "targets": '_all',
  "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.text()
  }
}],
```

Comment: Hi, i don't have the error now but it's not preventing the XSS attacks, in one of the columns i puted a javascript code and it's executed while loading the datatable.

Comment: That's a separate issue I would suggest starting a new question about.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The reason for "*Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.render.text is not a function*" is that it is not included in the version OP is using. The correct syntax *is* `$.fn.dataTable.render.text()`...

Comment: Hey Rory, yes, the first use of  `.DataTable` was clearly incorrect, but unfortunately your answer is as well :)  It makes the error to go away, but that is because the end result becomes `render: null ` ...`$.fn.dataTable.render.text()` was introduced in 1.10.10 ...

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood you point. Thank you for letting me know. I'll update the answer.