# Datatables rendering function doesn't prevent XSS attacks

Tags: jquery, datatables, xss

I'm using jQuery Datatables version 1.10.7 and I'm using the rendering function to prevent XSS attacks:

```
"processing" : true,
"bJQueryUI" : true,
"order" : [ [ 0, "asc" ] ],
"columnDefs": [    
               {                                 
                   "targets": '_all',
                   "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.text
               }    
             ], 
"aoColumns" : [
{
    "mData" : "name",
    "defaultContent" : " "
},
```

Table row :

```
<tr><td class="sorting_1"><script>alert('XSS !!');</script></td></tr>
```

The rendering function doesn't prevent the XSS attack and the javascript code is executed while loading the datatable.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: You need to refer to the renderer as a function, not as variable reference, as the documentation clearly states. i.e `$.fn.dataTable.render.text()`

Comment: I'm getting the following error when using it as a function :

 >Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.render.text is not a function

Comment: This is because `$.fn.dataTable.render.text()` not is included in the DataTables version you are using. It was the same deal with your [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51763352/1407478), the answer you have accepted is simply wrong. The error disappears if you use `$.fn.dataTable.render.text`, but the only reason for that is that you actually say `render: null`.  `$.fn.dataTable.render.text()` was added in version 1.10.10 -> **https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/**

Comment: I have made this fiddle to demonstrate proof of concept -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qt0jkrx8** try comment out `render: $.fn.dataTable.render.text()` ....

Comment: The problem was solved after upgrading to the latest version. Thanks davidkonrad